# How to download a file with Response object from ASP.NET without "Save as" Dialog?

Tags: c#, response

I have the following C# code:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=excel.xlsx");
Response.TransmitFile(@"C:\excel.xlsx");
```

Second save the file option:

```
Response.WriteFile(@"C:\excel.xlsx");
```

Third save the file option:

```
Response.Write(@"C:\excel.xlsx");
```

---

After executing those lines I'm able to download the file, but I do not want to see the "Save as" dialog window, just download automatically the file.

This configuration can be modified from the browser's "ask or not" but the idea is to do it automatically, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, is not. Is a security option from the browser.

Comment: Hi leandro, any other alternative?

Comment: @vtiktoker No, because is not your decision. You can "open" the file in the browser if the browser is capable, but what are you asking, not just is not on your control, also is wrong for securitiy reasons.